# Need help to install android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: My error 1]

Please help me fix this installation error. **Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Build-Tools 27 and 2 more SDK components were not installed** I keep getting that error everytime.When I click finish even I have the error **Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs** This message pop up.

[image: My error 2]

The Installer I downloaded is **android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows**

Comment: Clean uninstall android studio and remove any android-sdk files in your system. Then try fresh download and install from official page. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html More latest and stable versions are available

Answer (score 1):

You can download latest version of android sdk separately and then specify the path of this in android studio.